# What is the basis of description of matter and energy in our universe in the form of wave and particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, wave-particle-duality

1. What exactly does wave particle duality mean does it mean that an electron is a particle which is moving like a wave or does it mean that an electron and a photon is neither a wave nor a particle and something completely different or is it as if it’s sometimes a wave and the other times a particle or if it’s both simultaneously? Similarly for photons.
   (Is it like mass is nothing but compactly packed energy and similarly for energy, as in $E=mc^2$, which is described by wave particle duality as in the answer to the first question?)
2. Based on what have we got the two ideas of wave and particle? That is, how have we-on what basis, classified the behaviour of matter and energy as wave and particle? (Like we have classified matter into solid, liquid, gas, Bose-Einstein condensate and plasma based broadly on the inter particle forces of attraction, how is matter packed, the relative energies etc.)

Comment: You are almost asking for a course on quantum theory.  You really need a book for this (basically any introductory book on quantum theory).  There are also free courses of video lectrues on e.g. YouTube.

Comment: see this answer of mine for the electron as example of massive particle/wave duality https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238855/  and this for photon https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594861/

Comment: Alright I have edited the question and simplified it. Anna Mam’s description is really helpful. What however is the answer to the second question? And a brief answer to the first question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the wave-particle duality a real duality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46237/is-the-wave-particle-duality-a-real-duality)

Answer (score 0):

The basis is observation. The way to understand observation proved to be quantum mechanics. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics.